# WebGL line drawing issue

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am trying to draw simple shapes using WebGL LINES mode. These are my vertices:

```
<canvas width="200" height="200".../>

...

vertices.push(
    0.01,0.13, 0.03,0.15, 
    0.03,0.15, 0.09,0.15,
    0.09,0.15, 0.11,0.13,
    0.11,0.13, 0.11,0.03,
    0.11,0.03, 0.09,0.01,
    0.09,0.01, 0.03,0.01,
    0.03,0.01, 0.01,0.03,
    0.01,0.03, 0.01,0.13);
```

The picture shows the result which is far from my expectations:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZFuH.png)

I tried different things without success. How to fix it?

Here is a working example (DPI should be 1):

```js
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2", { antialias: false });
            var dpi = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;


            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
            gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            //vertex shader
            var vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
                in vec2 a_position;

                void main() {
                    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
                }
            `;

            var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
            gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

            //fragment shader
            var fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es
                precision highp float;

                out vec4 outColor;

                void main() {
                    outColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
                }
            `;
            var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
            gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

            //program
            var program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            gl.useProgram(program);

            //vertices
            var vertices = [];
            vertices.push(
                0.01,0.13, 0.03,0.15, 
                0.03,0.15, 0.09,0.15,
                0.09,0.15, 0.11,0.13,
                0.11,0.13, 0.11,0.03,
                0.11,0.03, 0.09,0.01,
                0.09,0.01, 0.03,0.01,
                0.03,0.01, 0.01,0.03,
                0.01,0.03, 0.01,0.13);

            //position attribute
            var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
            var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, vertices.length / 2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

I found that when anti-aliasing is turned on, the shape is more acurrate but blurry.

Comment: So how exactly are you projecting these?

Comment: I added a working example.

Comment: You're just getting rounding.  Your coordinates get multiplied by the viewport size and rounded down to pixels.  If you set the viewport to `(0,0,100,100)`, it looks correct.  And your `dpi` value is never used.  Right?

Comment: Have I missed something? I am trying to draw an 11x15 px shape. When I set the viewport to `(0,0,100,100)`, the shape is downscaled. By `dpi = 1` I meant setting the operating system scale to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that do draw the shape as expected the coordinates should be half pixel:

```js
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2", { antialias: false });


            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
            gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            //vertex shader
            var vertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
                in vec2 a_position;

                void main() {
                    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
                }
            `;

            var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
            gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

            //fragment shader
            var fragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es
                precision highp float;

                out vec4 outColor;

                void main() {
                    outColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
                }
            `;
            var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
            gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

            //program
            var program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            gl.useProgram(program);

            //vertices
            var vertices = [];
            vertices.push(
                0.015,0.135, 0.035,0.155, 
                0.035,0.155, 0.095,0.155,
                0.095,0.155, 0.115,0.135,
                0.115,0.135, 0.115,0.035,
                0.115,0.035, 0.095,0.015,
                0.095,0.015, 0.035,0.015,
                0.035,0.015, 0.015,0.035,
                0.015,0.035, 0.015,0.135);

            //position attribute
            var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
            var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, vertices.length / 2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```